# Why isn't the following Parse code returning an error?

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, ecmascript-6, parse-server

I have two functions: one that fetches objects and another that assigns those objects to an object's property:

```
var Building = Parse.Object.extend('Building')

store.findBuildings = () => {
  var query = new Parse.Query(Building)
  return query.find({
    success: function (building) {
      console.log('Succes:', building)
    },
    error: function (building, error) {
      console.log('Error:', error.message)
    }
  })
}

store.reloadBuildings = (obj, prop) => {
  store.findBuildings().then(buildings => {
    console.log('BUILDINGS', buildings)
    let buildings2 = _.map(buildings, (building) => building)
    console.log('BUILDINGS 2', buildings2)
  }, function (err) {
    console.log('Error:', err)
  })
}
```

If I do `console.log('BUILDINGS', buildings.toJSON())` in `store.reloadBuildings` the `console.log`s stop outputting anything, which means there was an error. However, `console.log('Error:', err)` doesn't display anything either.

Maybe I wrote the error handling in the wrong way?

**EDIT:**

I also tried this:

```
}).catch(err => {
  console.log('Error:', err)
})
```

But I get: `Uncaught TypeError: store.findBuildings(...).then(...).catch is not a function`

Comment: Regarding your edit: Parse doesn't use ES6-based Promises. They use their own implementation. Instead of `.catch()`, they have [`.fail()`](https://parse.com/docs/js/api/classes/Parse.Promise.html#methods_fail).

Comment: @Jonathan Lonowski Oh, you're right. Could you post this as an answer? Weird, I've never heard of `fail()` and I've been using ES6 and Parse for quite a while.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The promises used by Parse's SDK aren't entirely compliant with ES6 Promises – probably they were implemented before the standard was finalized (June 2015).

Their implementation defines a [`.fail()`](https://parse.com/docs/js/api/classes/Parse.Promise.html#methods_fail) method instead of the standard `.catch()`.

```
}).fail(err => {
  console.log('Error:', err)
})
```

---

In the first snippet, the reason `console.log('Error:', err)` isn't invoked is because the callback is bound to the Promise from `store.findBuildings()`, which was resolved and so has no use for any of its own `.fail()` callbacks.

```
var promise = store.findBuildings();

promise.then(success, failure);
```

To respond to errors thrown within a `.then()` callback, you'll have to bind to the next Promise created and returned by `.then()`. The error being thrown will cause that Promise to be rejected.

And, this is what you were trying to do in your edit.

```
var promise = store.findBuildings();

promise.then(success).fail(failure);

// same as...
var promise2 = promise.then(success);
promise2.fail(failure);
```